# Does $(-2)^{-x} \to 0$ in the real space?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Does a hyperbolic function of the form $\frac 1 {a^x}$, where the base number in the denominator is negative, tend to 0 on the real number line as $x \to \infty$? I can see that it tends to 0 in a complex space, but on a real number line the function is discrete.

Edit: I think if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ the limit would exist, so I'm going to define $x$ as being a real number for the purposes of this question.

Comment: @Surb: He is intending $n$ to mean a general real number. Then, for example, we could take $n=1/2$, whence issues arise.

To ahorn: Your use of $n$ to represent a non-integer value is distracting in this context. In future, please bear in mind notational conventions for ease of understanding.

Comment: @WillR thank you for pointing that out. I have changed the notation. Hopefully the comments will be edited.

Comment: What's $(-1)^{1/2}$? Clearly, you can't define it without $\Bbb C$. What's $(-1)^{1/3}$? Is it $-1$, or $\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$? Wolfram Alpha does the latter, in order to make $(-1)^x$ continuous. (Note that it is a cube root of $-1$; if you're not sure, try cubing it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, real exponents of negative numbers are not well defined, see below:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases

You are better off extending it in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: $(-2)^{-n}$ is of course well define !

Comment: Please re-read the question, it is specifically stated that $n \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Problem of notation :D (it's not clever to use $n$ for a real number).

Comment: So, to clarify, does the limit not exist?

Comment: The operation is not well-defined, so the question is not well-defined.